# Node JS and Mongoose How to get data from 2 collections?

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I need to get all docs from `service` collection and it's showing all records when i console `content`. In `content` collection there is field mids which is `media id` and all `images` are going to `media` collection. I need to get `media url` for specific service. But when i console `content.mids` it returns undefined .Do i need to change in query?

Code is attached for your reference.

```
// Controller   
 services: (req, res) => {

    Posts.find({content_type:'service'}).then(function(content) {
                console.log(content); //right
                console.log(content.m_ids); //showing undefined

            Media.findById(content.m_ids).then(media => {

                res.render('default/services', {content: content, reqUrl: req.url});  
            });              
    })

 }
```

Services Model

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const Schema = new Schema({

    content_type: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        maxlength:20
    },
    content_title: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        max:100

    },
    content_url: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        maxlength:200
    },
    content_description: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
    },
    content_full_description: {
        type: String,
        required: false,
    },
    pt_ids: {
        type: String,
        required: false,
    },
    pc_ids: {
        type: String,
        required: false,
    },
    m_ids: {
        type: String,
        required: false,
    },
    created_by_user_id: {
        type: String,
        default: 1,
    },
    created_on: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now
    },
    updated_on: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now
    },
    post_icon_svg: {
        type: String,
        required: false,
    }
});

module.exports = {Posts: mongoose.model('content_data', PostsSchema )};
```

// Media Model

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const MediaSchema = new Schema({

    media_name: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    media_title: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    media_alt: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    media_description: {
        type: String,
        required: false
    },
    media_url: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        unique: true
    },
    created_by_user_id: {
        type: String,
        default: 1,
    },
    created_on: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now
    },
    updated_on: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now
    }
});

module.exports = {Media: mongoose.model('media', MediaSchema )};
```

Comment: Can you add Service and Media model codes and sample documents as json to the question?

Comment: You need to keep postId in media schema, or mediaId in the post schema. Otherwise you can't join them.

Comment: mediaid is in post schema as m_ids

Comment: anyone have idea for this issue?

Comment: In the service model, you posted Post schema, can you add all related schemas and sample documents for each of the schemas in json format? And describe the expected output.

Comment: services are saving into Post schema. You can see a field "content_type" in post schema in this field i am saving content type like it's service or post?  i want to get media_url from media schema. media schema _id is m_ids in post scehma.